# pgadmin 4 maintenance job creation failed

Tags: macos, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I just setup postgresql 9.6 with pgadmin 4. I have a database i am trying to run maintenance on but get the error `maintenance job creation failed`. I have the postgres binary path set to the following:

[Preference settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw1by.png)

[Error when I try to run any maintenance option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/448RM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you check log for any errors?

Log location: **~/.pgadmin/pgadmin4.log**